# Get SparkContext from DataFrameWriter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

For the DataFrame's SparkContext I can get the underlying context by:

`df.rdd.sparkContext`

Is there any way I can achieve the same with the DataFrameWriter, ie. by getting the underlying DataFrame/Rdd?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question. You want to get the SparkContext from a DataFrameWriter ?

Comment: Exactly. I'm interested in getting anything from DataFrameWriter - DataFrame, RDD or at least underlying SparkContext since I get the writer  from some 3rd party and cannot just go back and get the DataFrame reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the only members which would allow this are private. You could do it with reflection: it's a bad idea, generally speaking, but if you really need this...

A better way: a `DataFrameWriter` must come from a `Dataset.write` call. Unless it's in third-party code, find where it happens and get the context there as well.

Comment: The issue here is all I have in the function parameters is a DataFrameWriter and I wanted to find some workaround to this problem, but if that's impossible then fine.